# Checking if Matrix has rows or not

Tags: matrix

how can I conditionally output rows of an matrix, if there are any? Eg:

```
{if matrixfield}
    <h2>Also check</h2>
    {matrixfield}
        <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a><br />
    {/matrixfield}
{/if}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Yep, just check to see if the matrix field `total_rows` are greater than 0

```
{if my_matrix_field:total_rows > 0}
    Matrix field has rows
{/if}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I dont have enough rep to make a comment.

So, I am not sure what you are looking for. The code below is an example how to work with conditionals for Matrix.

```
{matrixfield}

   {if no_results}
       No rows available
   {/if}

   {if '{row_count}' == '1'}
       <a href="{url_title}">{title} - First row</a>
   {/if}

  <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a>

   {if '{row_count}' == '{total_rows}'}
        <a href="{url_title}">{title} - Last row</a>
   {/if}
{/matrixfield}
```